# Working-Around Class.Method call, for non-static Classes/Methods

Tags: java, class, methods

```
public class MainClass { 
    public void main(String[] args) {
        Grid.simulator(args); //static method that I can actually call
        Engine.main;//what I want to call
    }
}
```

The problem is: `Engine.main` cannot be static. This is why:

```
class Engine {
    String command;
    public void main() {
        this.CommandLine(command); //Calls the Method which has the user input
        this.ProcessCommand(command); //Calls the Method that will process the input
    }
}
```

I understand that I can't call a non-static method, but I was thinking of a work-around:
Would it work if I assign a *something* to `CommandLine` and `ProcessCommand`, as if it was a non-initialized variable in a static context. Like so:

```
class SomeClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = null; 
        number = System.Nextint;
        System.out.print(number);
    }
}
     //In this code, either don't put it as static OR initialize 'number', even if as null.
```

Would something **similar** work for `this.Something` ? If Yes, how so?

Comment: Please please please format your code. This really is illegible.

Comment: Please try to provide a more complete code sample and try to clarify the explanation a bit. It's really difficult to follow as it stands.

Comment: Don't ask vague hypothetical questions. Write whatever it is you're asking and see what the results are.

Comment: Updated the Format. 
And regarding vague questions, well I have no absolute idea on how to do it. I can't figure out if it's possible to call a method without actually doing anything to it (so that I can call a static method while it is actually non-static). Similarly to how you initialize a variable before treating it in a static method

Comment: You didn't update the format, you broke it again. I have reversed it for that reason. You can see the results of your changes realtime in the box underneath your editing field. Writing uncompilable code doesn't break your computer, just start trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused about Java in a very basic way.

1. In Java, you generally name methods without starting them with a capital letter.
2. If `main` is not static, it will not be called, you will just get a very clear error message when you try to run the program.
3. You have to put parentheses around a method call whether or not there are any arguments to it. You have to use `Engine.main()` instead of `Engine.main`.
4. If you are trying to get user input, you can't pass the string to the method and expect the method to change what you pass to it. You need to return it or return it in a class variable.
5. No matter how hard you try, you can't set a number to `null`. In fact, setting the number to `null` is unnecessary here. Just set it to `System.Nextint`.
6. And, by the way, getting user input as an int is more complicated than that.

   ```
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   int number = in.nextInt();
   ```
7. And, your real problem: Just make `getInput` (what `CommandLine` should be called) and other such methods static. And don't use `this.method()`, use `method()`.

I think it is unlikely that you have every compiled this code. Well do it now and see how many errors you find (if that's your real code and not just a casual guess.)

Comment: Like I said, the number's part was merely an example. Even if you declare a variable, but don't initialize it you'll get an error if you are working in a static method, that was what I meant to demonstrate, adding a work around it, by initializing it to some value.

Comment: The problem is that to call a method, the method I am calling them to cannot be static, but to run, I need it to be static

Comment: You can call a method even if the method that is calling it is static. Just make the method itself static. In fact, it would be best for you to make *everything* static, to avoid confusion.

Comment: Which raises a problem, because I won't be able to use this.method

Comment: No, because you can just use `method()` and it will do *exactly the same thing*.

Comment: And by the way, to make code in comments, you surround the code with backticks, which are just below the esc key on your keyboard, `\`like this\``.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much. I managed to fix it by turning it into static and since `method()`has the same usage, it simplified things, a lot. By doing it like that, It became much more easier to code the rest of the methods. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: btw, yes the `class SomeClass` code was just an example, that I just wrote when asking the question as an example to what I thought I could do to fix it